# Huawei Account Kit Authorization Code Error : 1101

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am using account kit in my android project. By following the codelab in [this](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSAccounts/index.html#0) link.
After user successfully  logs in, the client uses the authorization code sent from the server to obtain the access token. But I am getting an **error code :1101** when I am trying to do that.

I do not know what might be causing the problem. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

According the official documentation, error code 1101 means

> The value of client_id in code or refresh_token is different from that of the input parameter.

Are you trying to decode the authorization code?  If so please transfer it directly without decoding.

Here is the guide for error lists and what they mean : [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/account-obtain-token_hms_reference-0000001050048618-V5)

Answer (score 0):

The error code 1101 could be caused by 1) the authorization code is expired and a new authorization code needs to be obtained 2) the format of redirect URL or refresh token is different from that of the input parameter.
Please check your sub-error codes from the following link.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-References-V5/account-obtain-token_hms_reference-0000001050048618-V5

For example, you can find the sub-error code from the returned status code:

```
{
```

"sub_error": 12304,
"error_description": "invalid client_secret",
"error": 1101

}